# Laravel - Can't handle MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-4

I am trying to customize the MethodNotAllowedHttpException error, but I am not getting anywhere.

```
#app/start/global.php

App::error(function(MethodNotAllowedHttpException $exception)
{
    Response::make("Test...", 503); 
});
```

It just shows up a blank/empty page.

However, if I replace the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` with `Exception` it works. But that shows up for alot of errors and I want only for this type.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you forget the `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException` statement ?

Comment: What Touki said should fix your issue. Remember to use correct namespaces throughout your app.

Comment: Doh! Thank you! So obvious, right... Using that completely solves the problem... :)

Comment: @touki: Why not submit your answer as an answer then? I want to give you real upvotes, not just comment upvotes.

Comment: @dequis This question is too localized and is unlikeley going to help future readers who searches for *"Can't handle MethodNotAllowed"* (asked: 6 months ago, views: 86 times). I don't  want to earn reputation for this kind of question. If you really want to thank me, you can always pick an answer of mine you find helpful and upvote it!

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5, exceptions should be handled in app/Exceptions/Handler.php like so:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        return abort('503');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

However, I wouldn't use 503 for these type of errors as it doesn't comply with the HTTP spec. A 405 would be more suitable if the method is not allowed for that path.

You then can create a view in resources/views/errors/405.blade.php to display something nice to the user.